# How do I read IP addresses in binary format from files in C++?

Tags: c++

How do I read IP addresses in binary format from files in C++?

Clarfication: The file contains 4 bytes of actual binary data. The ones and zeros below in text format are only for illustration purposes!

If I have a binary file that contains bits, which represented as zeros and one would look like:
00000001 00000000 00010011 00000111 00000010 00000000 00010011 00000111 
that represents the ip addresses 1.0.19.7 and 2.0.19.7

How do I read the 32-bit values from the binary file and turn them into an unsigned integer?

What is wrong with the code below?

```
  FILE *myfile = fopen("binaryipfile.bin", "r");    
   unsigned int ip;
     char string[32];
        while (fgets(string, 32, &myfile)) {
        sscanf(string, "%x", &ip);
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between *binary* and *base-2 ASCII*. How did you conclude that "%x" is meant for *binary*?

Comment: So the file isn't actually a binary file, it contains the digits `0` and `1` as *text*? With or without the spaces between the "bytes"?

Comment: As for parsing the input, loop over the string from beginning to end, remembering that the leftmost character is bit 31 and the rightmost is bit 0. Then use bitwise operations like *shift* and *or*. Of course, this is ***if*** the file is actually a text file, and not an actual binary file, in which case you read it into a 32-bit unsigned integer and you have your address all finished (endianness issues aside).

Comment: Does your file literally contain the textual representation of a binary number in *ones & zeros* or does it just contain 4 bytes of actual binary data?

Comment: Oh and lastly a little not about your use of `fgets`, the last argument is a `FILE *`, you're passing it a `FILE **`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Of course it is a binary file, the text from a Hex Editor is binary view to make it easier to understand what the file contains.

Comment: Then your first problem is your use of it as a *text file*. You should open in in binary mode, and you can't use text functions like `fgets` to read the data.

Answer (score 3):

To read 32 bits from a binary file, just use [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) to read into a 32-bit variable. Like

```
uint32_t address;
fread(&address, sizeof(address), 1, myfile);
```

You might have to convert the value using `htonl` if it's stored in a host endianness that differs from network endianness.

Of course, you must first open the file in binary mode:

```
FILE *myfile = fopen("binaryipfile.bin", "rb");  // Note the use of "rb"
```

---

To do in in C++ using the [C++ standard stream library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), it would be something like

```
std::ifstream file("binaryipfile.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

uint32_t address;
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&address), sizeof(address));
```

---

No matter if you use the C or C++ way, if you have multiple addresses then read in a loop, possibly putting the addresses into a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). This can be done much simpler if using the C++ function [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) function paired with [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::vector<uint32_t> addresses;
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<uint32_t>(file),
          std::istreambuf_iterator<uint32_t>(),
          std::back_inserter(addresses));
```

After this the vector `addresses` will contain all 4-byte values read from the file. If not all of the file contains addresses, you could use [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) instead.

You should also have some error checking, which I left out of my examples to keep them simple.

Comment: since the question is marked as C++, could you add the C++ idiomatic way too?

Comment: This answer was referenced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073202/read-binary-file-into-vector-of-uint32-t). Turns out that last bit with the `istreambuf_iterator` is wrong.