# Read binary file into vector of uint32_t

Tags: c++, vector, io, binaryfiles

There's a binary file `words.bin` containing multiple 4 byte integers. I want to read them from the file into a `std::vector` of corresponding size, which is `uint32_t`. Here's what I've tried first:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream f("words.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<uint32_t> wordvec(std::istreambuf_iterator<uint32_t>{f}, {});

    return 0;
}
```

However, I get this error message:

```
u32vec.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
u32vec.cpp:9:71: error: no matching function for call to 'std::istreambuf_iterator<unsigned int>::istreambuf_iterator(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
     std::vector<uint32_t> wordvec(std::istreambuf_iterator<uint32_t>{f}, {});
```

If I change both `uint32_t` to `char`, it does work, but this is not what I want.

My second try was writing the curly bracket notation explicitly, but then accessing the methods of `std::vector` gives a syntax error. This is the code:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream f("words.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<uint32_t> wordvec(std::istreambuf_iterator<uint32_t>(f), std::istreambuf_iterator<uint32_t>());

    wordvec.at(0);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the compiler output:

```
u32vec.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
u32vec.cpp:11:13: error: request for member 'at' in 'wordvec', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<unsigned int>(std::istreambuf_iterator<unsigned int>, std::istreambuf_iterator<unsigned int> (*)())'
     wordvec.at(0);
             ^~
```

This is the output of `g++ --version`:

```
g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Most vexing parse

Comment: stream buffer iterator iterate over `char`s, and nothing else. Trying to somehow transmogrify them into iterators over the some other datatype won't work the way you expect it to work, ignoring the issue of the most vexing parse, for the moment. Bottom line: you will have to extract everything yourself, four bytes at a time. C++ won't do it for you.

Comment: First paragraph in [cppreference's documentation for `std::istreambuf_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) says *std::istreambuf_iterator is a single-pass input iterator that **reads successive characters** from the std::basic_streambuf object for which it was constructed.* I **bold**ed. Looks like C++ won't give you the chance to shoot yourself in the foot with endian here.

Comment: Does the stream buffer iterator really only iterate over `char`s? I loosely orientated myself on the following answer, which does use another type for both the iterator and the destination vector: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35626906

Comment: Update: The linked answer seems to be faulty. Thanks to everyone for replying. If you put your comment into a separate answer I will gladly accept it.